# PHP Mysql : How to insert specific records from one db to another db different server?

Tags: php, mysql

db 1 Table 1

1. Name
2. Dob
3. Address
4. ID
5. Last Updated date

Specific Records(using where condition) from the above table has to be inserted or updated to another db 2 table 2 of different server.

Comment: If it is a one-time thing - dump everything, upload into another server, delete unnecessary records.

Comment: will be used frequently

Comment: Then.. open two connections, get date from, insert into another. Example here - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33929/how-can-i-copy-data-from-one-mysql-server-to-another-based-on-a-select-statement

Answer (score 0):

If its only for one time, just do it in any database editing tool like MySQL Workbench or SQLyog.

If you need to do it frequently, do it like this:

1. get a connection with db 1
2. fetch all the records needed from db1 table1 and put them in an array
3. close the connection with db 1 and open a connection with db 2
4. loop through the array with records and insert/update them in db2
5. close the connection with db2.

it shouldn't be that hard